# Elastic Query accepting only 4 characters

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-5

I am running a terms query in elastic search version 7.2, when I have 4 characters in my query, it works and if I add or remove any characters it's not working.

Working query:

```
{
"query": {
    "bool": {
        "must": [{
                "terms": {
                    "GEP_PN": ["6207"]
                }
            },
            {
                "match": {
                    "GEP_MN.keyword": "SKF"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
}
```

Result : [image]

Query that is failing :

[image]

Comment: sorry about that i forgot, actually you were right there is some issue with the analyzer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not failing, its not finding the result for your search-term, please note that [terms query are not analyzed](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) as mention in the docs.

> Returns documents that contain one or more exact terms in a provided
> field.

Please provide the mapping of your index and if its using the `text` field and you are not using custom-analyzer it will use `standard analyzer` which would split tokens on `-`, hence your terms query is not matching the tokens present in inverted index.

**Please see the [analyze API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html) o/p for your search-term, which explains the probable root-cause.**

```
{
    "text" : "6207-R"
}
```

**Tokens**

```
{
    "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "6207",
            "start_offset": 0,
            "end_offset": 4,
            "type": "<NUM>",
            "position": 0
        },
        {
            "token": "r",
            "start_offset": 5,
            "end_offset": 6,
            "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
            "position": 1
        }
    ]
}
```